# PHP multidimensional array compare and remove values against indexed array

Tags: php

I have a single array of suitable booking times and another multi-dimensional array which contains for each date an array of already booked times. I would like to iterate across each date and build another separate multidimensional array for each date which contains those times from the first array that are free to book.

```
$times = array("9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00");

$dates = array(
            "28/07/2018" => array("10:00", "11:00"),
            "29/07/2018" => array("10:00", "13:00"),
            "30/07/2018" => array("11:00", "13:00"));



// function to remove duplicates
function myArrayDiff($array1, $array2) {
    // loop through each item on the first array
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $row) {
        // loop through array 2 and compare
        foreach ($array2 as $key2) {
            if ($row['id'] == $key2) {
                // if we found a match unset and break out of the loop
                unset($array2[$key2]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return array_values($array2);
}

$array3 = myArrayDiff($dates, $times);

print_r($array3);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having and need help with? Its not clear from your question.

Comment: When you have an indented code block there is no need to enclose it with backticks (`\``). In fact, backticks are included in your code block and can easily mess up syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided function is obviously copied from somewhere and wont work with given data. All you need to do is diff times for each day (iterate days, and do diff with array_diff)

```
$times = array("9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00");
$dates = array(
            "28/07/2018" => array("10:00", "11:00"),
            "29/07/2018" => array("10:00", "13:00"),
            "30/07/2018" => array("11:00", "13:00"));

$filtered = [];
foreach($dates as $day => $taken_times) {
  $filtered[$day] = array_values(array_diff($times, $taken_times));
}

print_r($filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after because it wasn't completely clear, so I made some assumptions here.

I'm assuming that you want to get an array of times (the hour) that are preferred in the first array, and create a new array like the second, matching the hours that are available.

Note: I'm using newer php array syntax here because it's better than the ugly `array()` syntax of older php.

```
$preferred = [
    "9:00",
    "10:00",
    "11:00",
    "12:00",
    "13:00"
];

$available = [
    "28/07/2018" => [
        "10:00",
        "11:00"
    ],
    "29/07/2018" => [
        "10:00",
        "13:00"
    ],
    "30/07/2018" => [
        "11:00",
        "13:00"
    ]
];

$dates = array_keys($available);
$ideal = [];
// create an ideal array keyed by the available dates with empty array as values for now.
// useless now, but useful later.
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $ideal[$date] = [];
}
foreach ($available as $date => $hours) {
    foreach ($hours as $hour) {
        if (in_array($hour, $preferred) === true) {
            $ideal[$date][] = $hour;
        }
    }
}

print_r($ideal);
```

I'm certain there are more efficient ways to do this, but I think this is fairly readable.

Hope that helps. If I misunderstood what you wanted, can you clarify?